# Getting 'unrecognised selector' from NSNotificationCenter

Tags: objective-c, observer-pattern, nsnotificationcenter, couchbase-lite

I'm trying to implement an observer in the NSNotificationCenter.  Instead of using `self` as the observer I want to create a little object that does it:

```
typedef void (^ErrorCallback)(NSError*);
typedef void (^SuccessCallback)();
typedef void (^ReplicationChanged) (NSNotification*);

@interface SyncParams : NSObject

@property (copy) ErrorCallback errorCallback;
@property (copy) SuccessCallback successCallback;
@property (copy) ReplicationChanged replicationChanged;//this used to observe

- (void)replicationChanged:(NSNotification*)notification;

@end

@implementation SyncParams

@end
```

Then later I create an instance of the observer:

```
SyncParams* params = [SyncParams alloc];
params.replicationChanged = ^(NSNotification* notification) {
    //do stuff here
};
```

And finally add it to the NSNotificationCenter:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: params
                                         selector: @selector(replicationChanged:)
                                             name: kCBLReplicationChangeNotification
                                           object: replicationObject];
```

But I get this error: `Exception '-[SyncParams replicationChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff945c049a0' was thrown`

I'm very new to objective-c!  Any pointers?

Comment: What does the implementation of `replicationChanged:` look like?

Comment: I don't see, that `replicationChanged:` is implemented.

Comment: Is that not what tis is: `params.replicationChanged = ^(NSNotification* notification) {
    //do stuff here
}; ` ??

Comment: You ever debug this correctly? Im running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, I ended up with the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:kCBLReplicationChangeNotification object:repl queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification) {

    NSString *status;
    if (repl.status == kCBLReplicationActive) {
        NSLog(@"Repication in progress");
        status = @"in-progrss";
    } else if (repl.status == kCBLReplicationOffline) {
        NSLog(@"Sync in offline");
        status = @"offline";
    } else if (repl.status == kCBLReplicationStopped) {
        NSLog(@"Sync in stopped");
        status = @"stopped";
    } else if (repl.status == kCBLReplicationIdle) {
        NSLog(@"Sync in idle");
        status = @"idle";
    }

    NSError *error = repl.lastError;
    if(error) {
        status = @"error";
        NSLog(@"replication error %@", error.code);
    }

    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
                                 @"type": type,
                                 @"changesCount": @(repl.changesCount),
                                 @"completedChangesCount": @(repl.completedChangesCount),
                                 @"running": @(repl.running),
                                 @"status": status,
                                 @"suspended": @(repl.suspended),
                                 };

    [self sendEventWithName:@"replicationChanged" body:dictionary];

}];
```

I only ever get one callback though, when it starts up.